# Using foreign keys in file upload django

Tags: django

I have two models as follows:

```
class LabelModel(models.Model):
    labelled_image = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/label',
                                  db_column='path', default='Some Value')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "label_images"


class ControlModel(models.Model):
    control_image = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/control', db_column='path',
                                 default='Some Value')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "control_images"
```

Finally, I have a composite model as follows:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    labelled_image = models.ForeignKey(LabelModel, db_column='label')
    control_image = models.ForeignKey(ControlModel, db_column='control')
```

Now in my view, I have the following:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Path to files
        labelled_file = request.FILES['labelled_image']
        control_file = request.FILES['control_image']

        # How should I create the Document model instance?
```

The `DocumentForm` is as follows:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    labelled_image = forms.FileField(label='Select the Label image')
    control_image = forms.FileField(label='Select a Control image')
```

My question is how should I now create an instance of the `Document` model and save it. Do I need to first create instances of `LabelModel` and `ControlModel` and upload those files and then create the `Document` model instance or is there a way to do this in one go with Django?

[EDIT]

Following @sebb's comments I did the following:

```
label_model = LabelModel(labelled_image=labelled_file)
label_model.save()

control_model = ControlModel(control_image=control_file)
control_model.save()

newdoc = Document.objects.create(labelled_image=label_model,
                                 control_image=control_model)
```

This works. However, I wonder if I have to do these multiple `save` calls and in case one of those fails, it could be a bit of a pain to revert...

Comment: You have required `labelled_image` and `control_image` as far as I can see. So yes, firstly you need to create those two objects. Then just create an Document object with previously created two objects.

Comment: What is DoeucmentForm? is it for Document model?

Comment: @e4c5 Sorry missed the form code. I have added it now. (BTW: Awesome Sicilian user name!)

Comment: Unless you have a lot of other fields in those three models this is a lot of unnecessary hard work

Comment: @e4c5 It is separated because at some point they will need to be independent and need to be put together in a composite way.